# Insync application not working after update to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, insync

So recently I upgraded to 18.04 and I have been having problems with the Insync application ever since. The first thing to notice is that the system tray icon doesn't work. At first it was not appearing at all, and after a bit of googling I found that this is due to Gnome not supporting system tray icons. I tried a couple of suggestions like installing TopIcons, with the result that an icon now appears at the top right corner, but it does not respond to clicking at all. Interestingly, a Chrome icon recently appeared which opens up a task manager when clicked, indicating that tray icons can be functional. To be honest, I don't remember exactly what I did that got the icon to appear in the first place.

The biggest problem, however, is that Insync is simply not syncing my files. I still have access to my Google Drive folder in files, and it appears with the same special icon that it always does, with all my files in it, but it is not syncing any longer. After I boot, I get a message that Insync had to close, and I check the box to reload the application and send a report, but nothing happens. When I try to open Insync directly from Applications, nothing happens either.

I would really appreciate any advice on how to fix this.

Comment: I suggest asking on the company's forum, they are usually pretty responsive. https://forums.insynchq.com/  It's working on my 18.04 install but I use LXDE instead of Gnome.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the tip, I have gone ahead and posted there, though I would still appreciate whatever support people can give me here as well.

Comment: What happens if you install `sni-qt` by running `sudo apt install sni-qt` and reboot? (for the no-icon issue)

Comment: Hello, @silvascientist, did you resolved this issue?